# sitecore experience editor adding new datasource is slow

Tags: sitecore8.2, experience-editor

We are on Sitecore 8.2 with MVC and datasources for our renderings.  We have found that during development the adding/selecting of a datasource for a rendering is very quick, as one would expect.  But on our test servers, and even in production, this is excruciatingly slow (1-5 minutes).  I started to watch our resources on the machine in question and once a user creates a new datasource item the memory and cpu spike considerably.  I am looking for possible causes to this issue or areas that I can make some improvements.  We have not made any customizations to the pipe lines that are used when selecting/adding/creating datasources.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Have you compared the database memory between Test server and Production server?

Comment: being that it is SQL server, using the memory monitor on that machine will always show that all the memory allotted to it will be in use even when it is idle, so that is not much help.  But I have watched the calls to the server and have noticed nothing out of the normal (adding/updating items and such).